# Client cannot connect to test controller (VSTS)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, load-testing

I'm trying to setup a test rig in a virtual environment (labmanager), currently with no AD and accessing it from a dev machine (client) which is a member of an AD. Both agent and controller are instantiated in labmanager. I've created a local account (tfs2010testuser) on agent and controller, same username and password. Both agent and controller has a dns name and client, agent and controller all know these names. The user tfs2010testuser is admin on agent and controller. Furthermore tfs2010testuser is a member of TeamTestAgentService, TeamTestControllerAdmins and TeamTestControllerUsers. The controller is run under the tfs2010testuser account. Agent connects to the controller. Local firewalls are disabled on agent and controller, devenv.exe is allowed throught the client firewall. The following are the ports I can access from the client to the controller:

```
PORT      STATE SERVICE
135/tcp   open  msrpc
139/tcp   open  netbios-ssn
445/tcp   open  microsoft-ds
1720/tcp  open  H.323/Q.931
3389/tcp  open  ms-wbt-server
6901/tcp  open  jetstream
49152/tcp open  unknown
49153/tcp open  unknown
49154/tcp open  unknown
49155/tcp open  unknown
49157/tcp open  unknown
```

Can't really get nmap to show available port from the controller to the client.
I try to connect to the test controller with my AD user jmn. This user is created locally on the controller, member of administrators and TeamTestControllerAdmins and TeamTestControllerUsers. Passwords are identical on client and controller.
When I try to connect to the controller from vs2010 i get the error "The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found".

When I look in the event log on the client, I see the following:

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
The following information was included with the event: 
(devenv.exe, PID 2196, Thread 1) Timed out waiting for controller connect
the message resource is present but the message is not found in the string/message table
```

The timed out message is interesting. Why is this caused?

Nothing interesting is the event log for the controller.

I've been at this for 1½ days, trying to get this to work, read alot of posts regarding setting up hosts file, dns, mirrowed users, firewalls etc. Also read the ms troubleshooting guide, but I still haven't figured out the problem. Any thoughts?

Any information or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My error is no exact the same, but
for

> The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be
>   found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on
>   your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install
>   or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> (devenv.exe, PID 3652, Thread 7) ControllerProxy:
>   ProcessQueueTestRunWorkerException: System.TypeLoadException: Method
>   'add_FailedToReachController' in type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Agent.AgentProcessManager' from
>   assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.AgentProcessManager,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>   does not have an implementation.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.LocalControllerProxy.StopProcessNoLock(Boolean
>   invalidateRunId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.LocalControllerProxy.StopProcess(Boolean
>   invalidateRunId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.LocalControllerProxy.OnTestRunOperationError(Guid
>   runId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.LocalControllerProxy.OnQueueTestRunError(Guid
>   runId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestManagement.ControllerProxy.ProcessQueueTestRunWorkerException(TestRun
>   run, Exception e)
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

I fix instaling the visual studio 2012 update 2, hope it work for you